# DBCC SHRINKFILE shows no errors but doesn't shrink the log file

Tags: sql-server, logfile

I have a production DB restored in the dev environment on SQL Server 2012.
I wanted to shrink the log file to save HDD space. I looked through SO and other resources but none of the suggestions work for me.

I took the full DB backup and the Log backup. I set the recovery mode to simple. There's no mirroring set up. Yet the command DBCC SHRINKFILE does not shrink the file, but also does not show any errors.  The same command works perfectly well on other DBs in the same server. I also tried right click -> tasks -> shrink -> files -> shrink file to, and got the same result, i.e. no errors but the file size remains unchanged. 
What else can I try?

Comment: Run a few log backups in a row and checkpoints then try. If the end of the log file has data then shrink won't remove the space. Or just leave the log file alone is probably the best option.

Comment: What database recovery mode is currently used?

Comment: I tried both full and simple

Comment: did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen, even if you've followed the proper instructions of setting the database into `SIMPLE` recovery mode. Usually this happens because there is a virtual log still being used.

If you run:

```
DBCC LOGINFO;
```

You'll see if any virtual logs are in use (`Status` is 2). When shrinking files, empty virtual logs are physically removed starting at the end of the file until it hits the first used status. This is why shrinking a transaction log file sometimes shrinks it part way, but does remove all free virtual logs which you may expect.

This can happen if there is any active transactions still running, which you can debug by querying `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`.

Comment: I see some rows in sys.dm_tran_active_transactions and returned by DBCC LOGINFO (with status 2), but i still don't know what to do about them to make the log shrink?

Comment: For me log_reuse_wait_desc not returns any data. DBCC SQLPerf(logspace) return 99,99% Log Space Used DBCC LOGINFO returns 11059 rows, all Status = 2